# Spring Custom Annotation Integration Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

In my every Itegration test I have to add following annotations

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-context.xml")
@Transactional
```

I was thinking if I can create one custom annotation to group above annotations and instead of adding 3 annotations I can only one. I created following annotation for this purpose.

```
@Documented
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-context.xml")
public @interface IntegrationTest {
  String[] value() default {};
}
```

But when I add `@IntegrationTest` on my test class, it does not load the context. Can anyone please guide what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try to add @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) respectively.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@IntegrationTest
public ControllerTest
```

This is parent class.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-context.xml")
public @interface IntegrationTest
```

Also I would avoid using name of "@IntegrationTest", since it is a default annotation in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't going to work because your test classes don't inherit the annotations on your custom annotation. When JUnit runs your test class it doesn't find the @RunWith annotation and so it uses the standard test runner which doesn't know anything about Spring.

The best that you could do is create your own custom [JUnit test runner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-runners) and attach it to all of your test classes like @RunWith(MyIntegrationTestRunner.class). That custom test runner would then have to do all of the hard work of loading spring context and making your test class transactional. It's probably more trouble than it's worth unless you have a burning desire to learn about the inner-workings of JUnit and Spring.